# Path Problems while creating Page

Tags: coldfusion

Working on the new site on my localhost which is:

```
localhost:8500/myproject/index.cfm
```

i am calling the files inside the index.cfm as `<cfinclude template="common/js.cfm">`, it loads the files but when i click the files in view source of the webpage, it takes me to the `404 error`.

How can i set this up so it looks inside the folder, i tried prepending the `/` to the common folder, but that did not worked either

So is any CF based solution, rather than in `IIS` or something else because the application might be deployed in `unix` in future so i am not sure what to do here

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your `common` folder present inside `myproject` ? another option you can create a mapping in admin if your `common` folder present at some other location.

Comment: yes it is inside the myproject, well i can create mapping, but i do not want to because this on local will work but wanna gets deployed later on do not know where so thinking what is best approach to make it through cf

Comment: The issue lies in the fact that you are using the built in web server and have your project in a sub directory. So, your project's web root is not the same as your ColdFusion web root. I suggest using Apache or IIS as your web server for development. I know you said you prefer not to, but it really is the best solution.

Comment: Also, what is the output of js.cfm? The problem may exist in the HTML that is output form that file rather than the `cfinclude` of the file. Please update the question to show the output from js.cfm.

Comment: that js.cfm includes nothing, it is a just of text inside it, nothing all. Agree on ur part of making change in the iis but what i am looking in cf based solution. i hope u understand

Comment: If the js.cfm file 'includes nothing' why is it even there? Show the code that exists in js.cfm. I know you want a CF based solution, but a Cf based solution is not the right solution. Sorry, but I don't like helping people implement a bad solution. The solution to your problem is to use IIS or Apache in development. Why are you so resistant to this?

Comment: The fact that the application will be deployed in Unix means nothing...at all.

Comment: I agree with @ScottStroz. Just use Apache and be done with it. Also you're not articulating yourself very well at all. Can you please just include your code, as has been requested. The *relevant* bits of `index.cfm` and `js.cfm`. I am also very cautious about the fact you have a file "js.cfm". It suggests you have JavaScript in a CFM file, which is... less than ideal. Lastly, read this lot: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html (that page, the pages I link to). And revise your question accordingly.